# How to write a list to text file with index in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I have already written a code which will write a list to text file based on the index. I would like to add row numbers for each element.

```
with open('C://path/riskcontent.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
for item in content:
    file_handler.write("{}\n\n".format(item))
```

Output:

```
sentence
sentence
sentence
```

My desired output is:

```
1. sentence
2. sentence
3. sentence
```

How will I be able to add the indexing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution that jumps into mind:

```
with open('C://path/riskcontent.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    index = 1
    for item in content:
        file_handler.write("{}. {}\n\n".format(index, item))
        index += 1
```

A bit more Pythonic way is to just use enumerate function:

```
with open('C://path/riskcontent.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    for index, item in enumerate(content):
        file_handler.write("{}. {}\n\n".format(index + 1, item))
```

The +1 is there to adjust for the 0 based indexing.

Comment: perfect thanks so much! I will accept the answer as soon as it is available